# JavaScript setInterval increase and decrease variable

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with creating a variable that first will increase value (for example) form 0 to 10, and after that it wil go back from 10 to 0.
So 0,1,2,3...10,10,9,8,7...0 (and so on)
The main idea looks like this:

```
var count = 10;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 500); 

function timer() {
  count = count-1;

  if (count == 0) {
        count = 10;
    }

}
console.log(counter);
```

But it will only go from 0 to 10 all the time. How to make that 'comeback' thing? Thank you for help.

Comment: Just do `count mod `0` which, in Javascript, will look like: `count%10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the increment value

```
var count = 10;
var counterIncrement=-1;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 500); 

function timer() {
  count = count+counterIncrement;
  if (count == 0 || count == 10 ) {
        counterIncrement = -counterIncrement;
    }
  console.log(count);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that produces the correct output (with doubled zeros and tens) but is much shorter than @Teemu's one:

```
var count = 0, step = 1;
var counter = setInterval(function() {
    if (count<0 || count>10) // when we're outside the range
        count += step *= -1; // change direction and go back into
    console.log(count);
    count += step;
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution as I understood :

```
var count = 0;
var flag = false;
setInterval(function(){timer()}, 500); 

function timer() {
  console.log(count); 
  if (flag){
    count = count - 1;
  }
  if(!flag){
    count = count + 1;
  }

  if (count =< 0) {
     flag=false;
  }
  if (count >= 10) {
     flag = true;
  }

}
```

Comment: +1, but just pass the function directly: `setInterval(timer, 500)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `setTimeout()`s instead of `setInterval()`, something like this:

```
var count = 0, dir = 1, end = [0, 10], index = 1, counter,
    timer = function () {
        console.log(count);
        if (count === end[index]) {
            dir = -dir;
            index += dir;
            counter = setTimeout(timer, 500);
            return;
        }
        count += dir;
        counter = setTimeout(timer, 500);
    };
counter = setTimeout(timer, 500);
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaLDS/1/).

And as Bergi stated, works also with `setInterval()`:

```
var count = 0, dir = 1, end = [0, 10], index = 1,
     counter = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(count);
        if (count === end[index]) {
            dir = -dir;
            index += dir;
            return;
        }
        count += dir;
    }, 500);
```

[A live demo with interval at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaLDS/3/).

The advantage of using a separate `end` array is, that you can dynamically change the limits, if needed.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, does it?

Comment: @Bergi It does, it let's you to control the flow, and add double `10`s and `0`s to the log with a delay as well. Please notice "`0,1,2,3...10,10,9,8,7...0` in the question. Looks like my answer is the only one here which takes care of this.

Comment: I meant the `setTimeout`. Your function would work with `setInterval(timer, 500)` quite as well.

Comment: @Bergi Indeed it [does](http://jsfiddle.net/NaLDS/2/), I just didn't notice that before. Thanks for a tip : ).

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see there is that in the line

```
var counter = setInterval(timer, 500);
```

setInterval is returning you an ID that you can then use to call clearInterval and stop the sequence of calls to timer(). It is not returning you the value of count.

What you want, IMHO is something like this:

```
var counter = 10;

setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter - 1;

    if (counter < 0) {
        counter = 10;
    }
    console.log(counter);
}, 500);
```

Comment: @DevZer0 mentioned this already, but that's not the actual problem. He wants to avoid the jump from `0` to `10` and increment ten times instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 10;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 500); 

function timer() {
    if(!this.diff) this.diff=-1;
    count += this.diff;

    if(count==0 || count==10) this.diff=-this.diff;

    console.log(count);
}
```

This way, you don't pollute global namespace.

Comment: Using `this` from a `setInterval`-called function *does* pollute the global namespace, in contrast to OPs code.